# How to add fade in fade out effect on mouseover and mouse out?

Tags: jquery

How to add fade in fade out effect on mouseover and mouse out?

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery(".logo img").mouseover(function() { 
var src = "<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/kalfany/images/logo-<?php echo $this->language; ?>-hover.png";
 jQuery(this).attr("src", src);
}).mouseout(function() {
 var src = "<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/kalfany/images/logo-<?php echo $this->language; ?>.png";
 jQuery(this).attr("src", src);
}); });
</script>
```

and i got answer of my Question from here

http://bavotasan.com/2009/creating-a-jquery-mouseover-fade-effect/

and this whatever i looking for
So, best Answer is mine ;)

Comment: Help us help you. What is your problem, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: You could also be specific in selecting the image with correct selection criteria. You are selecting all the `IMG`s in a container having `class=logo`. If its not the case try using `jQuery('img.logo')`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rTdQC/1/ is this what u want??

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this...

```
$('.logo img').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
  }
);
```

But I was thinking it might not work because if once it completely fadeOut the hoverOut would call by its self. You can try add a div over the image and hide the image instead the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this...

```
$(".logo img").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});​
```

Comment: but there are two difference images those would be change on mouse over and i want fade effect on this shuffling.

Comment: @RjSyedHassanRaza this ans would work help yourself for making a good structure and use this script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for some kind of crossfade you could use

```
 jQuery("img").mouseover(function() { 
     var src = "http://www.josephmccaffery.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/logo_google_x-150x150.png";
     jQuery(this).fadeOut(300,function(){
         jQuery(this).attr("src", src).fadeIn();
     })
}).mouseout(function() {
     var src = "http://techteen.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Google-Logo-Square.png";
     jQuery(this).fadeOut(300,function(){
         jQuery(this).attr("src", src).fadeIn();
     })
});
```

​

[jsfddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HpmN7/181/)

Glitch may appear if images are not loaded.

Comment: you can preload them by `mInImg= new Image(); mInImg.src = 'mousein.png';`